# Capture PC screen continuously to create a video

Tags: video, video-capture

I am to create an educational video. I have to capture continuous screen shots as a video as well as the audio. Please explain me what software that can I use in this process?

Bellow is an example video clip similar to which that I want to produce:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jl_sud5Fak&feature=fvsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Windows [Media Encoder Version 9](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5691ba02-e496-465a-bba9-b2f1182cdf24&displayLang=de) (sorry, I only have the German link at hand right now) to do the screen capturing, and Microsoft MovieMaker to assemble instructional movies. I capture non-moving images by simple PrintScreen (... and all free ;-) ).

It works very well for instructional videos, if I choose the encoding parameters wisely (5 fps, higher masterframe interval, etc.) and if I am consequent about media size (i.e. all programs use same -say- 800x600 ... don't mix). I even can do shots of (fast-moving) animated GoogleEarth up to 640x480 on my Laptop.

Hope that helps - good luck

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Techsmith's Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) to be quite good for screen video capture, though it's not freeware/OSS.

Comment: I thought Jing was free - at least the basic version.

Answer (score 1):

Screen Video Recorder is able to [record everything on PC screen](http://screenvideorecorder.net) to video files . It offers several modes of recording, custom area, full screen etc. I can add my voice into files through microphone. It is very suitable for making tutorials.